# Response to "Do you want to go to the cinema this weekend?"

Tags: conversation

My brother showed me this question from his English language test:

Tom: Do you want to go to the cinema this weekend?
Marry:
(A) Yes, please.
(B) OK, who are you going with?

Both (A) and (B) sound weird to me. I don't think "please" and "OK" are proper responses to invitations. I would say something like "Sure. Which movie?"

What would a native speaker say?

Comment: "Yes, please" is a response to *an offer*, not an invitation. The other response is correct and natural

Comment: "Yes, please" suggests you think the other person will pay - an offer, as gotube says. A child might say it if their parent is offering to take them, but it would be less common between friends or romantic partners (unless it's the kind of relationship where the man has all the money and power). Also, do you mean Mary not Marry?

Answer (score 1):

Option A is awkward because it's an informal invitation. Contrast with a more formal setting in which a waiter asks, "Would you like some cheese on your soup?"  In that case, "Yes, please." is appropriate.

Option B is correct, and is very similar to your suggestion.  You basically gave an informal affirmative along with a follow-up question to seek more information and continue the conversation.  What you're finding awkward is the content of Mary's question because it's not what you would ask.  In Mary's case, she was interested in who else was going. It's interesting, and perhaps a little awkward, that she presumed that there was someone else, but it'd be up to Tom to either tell her or let her know it was just him.  We might imagine that Mary's thoughts were whether or not this was a group event or perhaps a date request, but she didn't want him to think she presumed it was a date.

So the presumption that someone else was coming is a subtle hint that she was not automatically thinking of this just the two of them, or as a date.  Compare that with if she had said, "Ok, would you like to get dinner after?" or "Ok, what time would you like to pick me up?" which are more in line with the presumption of a date.

And, of course, your option is fine too. "Sure. Which movie?"  Note that your option is focused more on the external factors about the event rather than the relationships involved.